# Celery connect to remote server broker_url

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I'm daemonizing celery following the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html).

My BROKER_URL has been set in the following format:-  `'amqp://<user>:<password>@<ip>/<vhost>'`.

So, when I start celery manually, `celery worker -A app_name`, it connects with the remote server. But when I daemonize it, it connects with the localhost amqp. Any reason why?

Here is how I create my celery object:-

```
app = Celery('c26_search')    
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
)
print app.conf.BROKER_URL  # prints remote url
```

My settings.py file:-

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
BROKER_URL = `'amqp://<user>:<password>@<ip>/<vhost>'`
```

Why is it acting so weirdly? Even it prints the remote IP url, but still tries to connects with the local amqp?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the answer to the question:-

Pass broker url is `CELERY_OPTS` as `CELERYD_OPTS="-n worker2.%h --broker=amqp://<user>:<password>@<ip>/<vhost>"` in celeryd file.